# iPhone SDK: Programmatically change IBAction

Tags: iphone, uibutton, ibaction

Is there a way I can programmatically change the IBAction of a UIButton?

I know I can just create two buttons and use button.hidden = BOOL, but I'd much rather just change the IBAction itself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sure. You can use `addTarget:forControlEvents:` and `removeTarget:action:forControlEvents:` to manage the connections between action methods and controls manually. Both methods are in `UIControl`.

Comment: ok, so I would call [self addTarget:button action:theIBAction forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

Comment: [button addTarget:self action:theIBAction forControlerEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown], assuming that self responds to theIBAction

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand the question? Why not have the IBAction call a custom method and put some logic about which action to take in that method?

Comment: because why do it with your own logic when Apple provides the logic for you :)

Comment: I don't think I would consider hooking up and removing IBActions as 'logic'.
And if you're considering the MVC model, I would think this would be a better solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Sure:

[-removeTarget:action:forControlEvents:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006779-RH2-SW5) to remove the old action

[-addTarget:action:forControlEvents:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006779-RH2-SW4) to add the new action